# grails No tests found for given includes when integration test files anld unit test files both exist

Tags: testing, integration

I got a strange problem for grails 3.2.6

I create a integration test  and a unit test by grails command

```
src
 --integration-test
  --groovy
    --it
      --test01

 --test
  --groovy
    --ut
      --test02
```

When I run the integrationt-test test01, I got an error
***No tests found for given includes***

If I delete ut.test02,
I got a message says test passed.

How to solve that?

Answer (score 3):

My hierarchy  is created automatically.

Anyway I solved by adding -integration in the configuration command line
like this

```
test-app it.test01 -echoOut -integration
```

Answer (score -1):

You are accessing your integration-test at the wrong place. 
Please put your hierarchy like this

```
--test
  --integration-test
    --groovy
      --it
        --test01

    --groovy
      --ut
        --test02
```